# ESP32 DevKitC Development on board LED blinking unintentionally

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, platformio

I wanted to create a simple HelloWorld program with my new `ESP32 DevKitC Development` module but I am confused that my `LED` is blinking even though I don't specify it in the program.

My code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define LED 2

int i = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);  
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  i++;
  Serial.print("I am running and calculating:"); Serial.println(i);
  delay(1000);
}
```

My environment:

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

I can see in my terminal the `Serial.print` output with the correct `i` values:

[image]

- But the on board LED is still blinking even though on line 11 I
  specifically set the pin to `LOW`.
- Strange thing is that the LED is blinking perfectly in sync with the `Serial.print` output.
- I am using VS code with PlatformIO, I have tried erasing the flash, rebuilding the program, cleaning it, uploading and nothin helped (even tried the verbose build and verbose upload).

### What can be the cause of this?

Comment: There are different versions of DevKitC. Which version do you have? I have V4 and it only has one LED, which represents 5V power being on. It does not have an onboard LED that I can program. As Tarmo indicates in his answer, some boards have an LED connected to the serial port tx and/or rx. So that's likely what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two LEDs which blink whenever there's UART traffic in either direction. You can't control them.

Comment: Thank you! That was the case :) silly of me :D